# Substring C from string like folder1/file1.txt

Tags: c, string, substring, substr

i have strings like "folder1/file1.txt" or "foldername1/hello.txt" and i need to take the substring that identify the folder name with the slash (/) included 
(example: from "folder1/file1.txt" i need "folder1/"). 
The folders name are not all with the same length.
How can i do this in C?? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, find the position of the slash with strchr:

```
char * f = "folder/foo.txt";  // or whatever
char * pos = strchr( f, '/' );
```

then copy into a suitable place:

```
char path[1000];   // or whatever
strncpy( path, f, (pos - f) + 1 );
path[(pos-f)+1] = 0;    // null terminate
```

You should really write  a function to do this, and you need to decide what to do if strchr() returns NULL, indicating the slash is not there.

Comment: You migth want to find the slash starting from the end of the string using strrchr()

Comment: Depends if he wants the first directory in the path or the whole shebang - most OS's have a function to do the latter, so I assumed the former.

Answer (score 3):

Find the last '/' character, advance one character then truncate the string.  Assuming that the string is modifiable, and is pointed to by `char *filename;`:

```
char *p;

p = strrchr(filename, '/');
if (p)
{
    p[1] = '\0';
}

/* filename now points to just the path */
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the strstr() function:

```
char *s = "folder1/file1.txt";
char folder[100];

char *p = strstr(s, "/");
if (0 != p)
{
    int len = p - s + 1;
    strncpy(folder, s, len);
    folder[len] = '\0';
    puts(folder);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you work on a POSIX machine, you can look up the [`dirname()`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dirname.html) function, which does more or less what you want.  There are some special cases that it deals with that naïve code does not - but beware the weasel words in the standard too (about modifying the input string and maybe returning a pointer to the input string or maybe a pointer to static memory that can be modified later).

It (dirname()) does not keep the trailing slash that you say you require.  However, that is seldom a practical problem; adding a slash between a directory name and the file is not hard.